# $scope saved is the scope of the last directive in a nested hierarchy

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I wanted to nest directives and have each of them their own separate scope. However, when I click on any ID button, I get ID = 3 everytime.

Live copy of my codes here.
http://plnkr.co/edit/Lg29CkN7MkEBsI7uNXR3?p=info

Here's a part of my html file:

```
    <tcp-widget id="1">
        <tcp-widget-header>
            <input type="button" value="ID = 1" ng-click="printId()"/>
        </tcp-widget-header>
        <tcp-widget-body>
            <div style="text-align:left; margin:0 auto; border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; padding: 5px;">
                <div style="color:red">RED by Taylor Swift</div>
            </div>
        </tcp-widget-body>
    </tcp-widget>

    <tcp-widget id="2">
        <tcp-widget-header>
            <input type="button" value="ID = 2" ng-click="printId()"/>
        </tcp-widget-header>
        <tcp-widget-body>
            <div style="text-align:left; margin:0 auto; border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; padding: 5px;">
                <div style="color:blue">BLUE by Big Bang</div>
            </div>
        </tcp-widget-body>
    </tcp-widget>

    <tcp-widget id="3">
        <tcp-widget-header>
            <input type="button" value="ID = 3" ng-click="printId()"/>
        </tcp-widget-header>
        <tcp-widget-body>
            <div style="text-align:left; margin:0 auto; border: 1px solid black; width: 300px; padding: 5px;">
                <div style="color:yellow">YELLOW by Coldplay</div>
            </div>
        </tcp-widget-body>
    </tcp-widget>
```

Here's the code for my widget:

```
(function(app) {
  app.directive('tcpWidget', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        id: "="
      },
      controller: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        this.printId = function() {
          alert("print id : " + $scope.id);
        };
      }
    };
  });
})(app);
```

Here's the code for my widget header:

```
(function(app) {
    app.directive('tcpWidgetHeader', function() {
        return {
        restrict: 'E'
                , require: "^tcpWidget"
        , link: function(scope, iElem, iAttrs, ctrl){
                    scope.printId = ctrl.printId;
                }
    };
    });
})(app);
```

Comment: What does "fail to do so" mean exactly? What is failing? What is your desired outcome? And by "separate scope" do you mean isolate or child?

Comment: What is your desired outcome? => When I click ID = 1, I get 1. When I click ID = 2, I get 2. And so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens here is that `tcp-widget-header` shares the scope - i.e. it uses the default `scope: false`. This means that when you set something on the scope, like you do with

```
scope.printId = ctrl.printId;
```

the last `tcp-widget-header` "wins" and sets `scope.printId` - which all will use - to "its" `tcp-widget` controller. Hence, all will call that controller function where `$scope.Id === 3`.

So, a quick fix is to add `scope: true` to the directive definition. This will create a child scope for each `tcpWidgetHeader`:

```
.directive('tcpWidgetHeader', function() {
   return {
     scope: true,
     // ... whatever you have
   }
});
```

**But, wait!!!** WHY do `tcp-widget-header` directives share same the scope to begin with, and not in isolate scope of their parent?

The reason is that the scopes of child DOM elements of a directive are not in the scope hierarchy of that directive's scope - as distinct from directives and expressions in the `template` of that directive. So, from scope perspective, they all "live" in the outer scope, shared by all the `tcp-widget`, `tcp-widget-header`, and `tcp-widget-body` directives.

Answer (score 0):

Your tcp-widget-header does not have isolated scope so you are modifying the same (outer) scope all the time when you set scope.printId in the link function.

Comment: I tried adding scope: {id: "="} and I could not longer call my link functions in tcp-widget-header.

Comment: you're not calling printId() on the isolated scope -- you're calling printId() on the outer scope.- that function does not exist.